# How do a specify get_absolute_url() on a view when the model isn't clear?

Tags: django, permalinks

I have a place in my Django app where I need to construct a callback to my domain after a third-party auth, but I'm stuck on how to do this since that view in question doesn't really map to one model (or rather, the view code references multiple models), and the docs for get_absolute_url() construction and permalinks all reference models.

For instance, in my template I currently have something like:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger large" href="http://to/third/party?api_key=noneyobiz&cb=http://localhost:8000/signup">Join via Somethingorother</a>
```

the line for this view in urls.py is:

```
    url(r'^signup/$', 'signup', name="signup"),
```

I want the hardcoded 'http://localhost:8000/signup' to be dynamic.  I'm hoping this functionality doesn't depend on my using generic views.  Actually I don't understand why generating a permalink is even tied to models at all, it seems like it should only depend on the urlconf.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`permalink` is a thin wrapper of `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`. Its belongs to django.db.models to be a shortcut because we usually write `reverse` inside `get_absolute_url` of models. So use reverse here

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
path = reverse('signup')
```

*Update*

To use absolute URI, you could

- hardcode in settings or use something like `Site.objects.get_current()` w/ the path you get from `reverse` or `url` to get the absolute URI, as Daniel suggested.
- If your callback URI is in the same domain w/ the view rendering the template, you could rely on [`request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) to get actual absolute URI:

  `request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('signup'))`

Furthermore, you may want to escape the URI in [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode), like `{{ absolute_uri|urlencode }}`. or in view through `urllib.quote` or `urllib.urlencode`

Comment: See my comment on Daniel Roseman's answer.  I don't want to hard-code the domain, and from what I can tell in the interactive shell, this answer just returns the path as well.

Comment: request.build_absolute_uri() is exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`permalink` is only for the use case when you *are* referencing a model directly. To find a non-model-based URL, you can use the `url` tag - in your case, `{% url signup %}`.

Comment: I don't believe the url template tag will work in this case.  Remember, the url needs to be an absolute URL because it's being sent as a callback in a third-party auth.  Everywhere else I use {% url %} in my project it just renders the path.

Comment: Well, that's not what you originally asked, which was to do with how to find the URL without a model. As you've noted, neither `url` or `reverse` (and `get_absolute_url`) return the full URL including domain. In fact, that information isn't available within Django itself, unless you tell it specifically. You can use the sites framework for this, or simply define a domain in settings.py, then prefix the result of the `url` tag with that value.